# How to bundle configuration files in an executable jar file in java

Tags: java, executable-jar, software-design

I want to include some configuration file to my executable jar file, however from ecliplse I seem to be unable to do so. There is no option to add local files at the time of jar creation. The point of trying to do so is to make the default configuration file available from anywhere the jar is called, and not from its source location. E.g., if I call a jar from a different location using a relative path the config doesn't gets executed even if it is there in the jar location itself. So everytime I want to run the executable I have to call the jar from its source location. Want to fix this issue with bundling the config(which is a text file in this case) within the jar itself. Can somebody please help me? If this is not directly possible what can be a workaround in this case? I'm sure there are softwares which uses default configurations bundled with themselves. I'm new to the forum so if anyone wants to correct any text in the question or better it, is welcome.

Comment: could you please add your code whatever you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want the text file inside the jar itself.

### How do I read that text file from my java code then?

Let's say your jar looks like this (let's assume we manage to get that text file in there somehow):

```
jar tvf Arunavo.jar

439 Wed Sep 26 20:45:34 CEST 2019 com/arunavo/main/default-config.json
1439 Wed Sep 26 21:40:34 CEST 2019 com/arunavo/main/Main.class
```

Then, in your `Main.java` file, you'd write:

```
try (InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("default-config.json")) {
    String data = new String(in.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // do something with your config here...
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

This works because `default-config.json` is in the same 'folder' as Main.class is. If you want to go from the 'root' of the jar, you'd do: `.getResourceAsStream("/com/arunavo/main/default-config.json")` which would also work.

### How do I get that text file in my jar then?

Generally, eclipse continually 'compiles' any file in any folder marked as a 'source folder' in your project config. It compiles java files by, well, compiling them. It 'compiles' any other file (a non-class, non-java file) by copying it over. So.. just... put that config file right next to your java file.

Note that using an IDE as a build system is not something I (or anybody, really) would recommend: They just aren't build systems. Yes, eclipse has an 'export to jar' feature but it is extremely limited in what that can do. Invest a little bit of time in knowing how to use maven or gradle. Both of these generally work with the following directory structure:

```
src/main/java/com/arunavo/main/Main.java
src/main/resources/com/arunavo/main/default-config.json
```

maven (and gradle, out of the box), 'compile' anything in `src/main/java` by throwing it at `javac`, and 'compile' anything in `src/main/resources` by copying. You can then tell your IDE that this is a maven (or gradle) project and the IDE will just get it automatically from there.

You can always run `jar tvf yourjar.jar` and check that the config file is in there, and in the right place, to check if your build, be it via eclipse's export features or mvn/gradle, is doing it right.

NB: If you set eclipse up right, so put the config file in the same place as where `Main.java` lives for a plain eclipse project, or in the appropriate `src/main/resources/com/arunavo/main` directory if it's a maven-java project, then running your application from within eclipse using e.g. the debugger will find the config file just fine.

Comment: This is great. I'll try and confirm if this is working. On the running from eclipse part, yes running from eclipse doesn't make an issue, executing as a standalone program via jar creates the problem. Anyway, I'll try that getResourceAsStream solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, working like a charm. Only thing is the concept of compilation process in an IDE such as eclipse is a little different than the usual command line javac process. We need to declare a folder as source folder and then that non-java unit gets copied over to bin as earlier mentioned. Otherwise, its bit of a google search.. :)